# Using DDL command Create User with iBatis for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ibatis, ddl

I was trying to execute the DDL command for Oracle database, using iBatis.
I want to execute below query using iBatis, how should I execute. I am using struts 1.2 for coding.

```
CREATE USER USER1..;
```

I have tried using the  element of iBatis, but its doesn't work.
Please anyone provide me quick solution for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL is not officially supported in iBatis, but still many times it is executed successfully with iBatis.
I have taken a simple DDL command for creating user, which runs correctly in Oracle.

```
CREATE USER MYUSER IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;
```

Then used mapped statement in iBatis. The `<statement>` mapped statement can hold any SQL statement. I referred Mapped Statements for iBatis from [this](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s03.html) link.
Then I have created statement for iBatis with create user DDL and passed a parameter class as `UserToCreate`.

```
<statement id="createUser" parameterClass="UserToCreate">
   CREATE USER #userName# IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
</statement>
```

The **UserToCreate.java** file is a bean holding data related to user to be created.

```
public class UserToCreate{

    private String userName;

    // Any other field variable

    //Getter Setter methods
}
```

Now for calling the Create User iBatis statement just write use code:

```
UserToCreate user = new UserToCreate();
user.setName("MYUSER"); 

// sqlMap is an object of ibatis SqlMapClient
sqlMap.update("createUser", user);
```

This will create a new Oracle User, as specified by the user name in variable `userName`.